# One liner to remove JS object properties with empty string

Tags: javascript

I have a JS object here

```
 {
    "test1" : "",
    "test2" : "apple",
    "test3" : "oranges",
    "test5" : ""
  }
```

Is there a JS one-liner that can filter out all the properties with empty strings?

Expected result:

```
 {
    "test2" : "apple",
    "test3" : "oranges",
  }
```

Comment: Why does it matter how many lines it takes?

Comment: I was looking for a more elegant solution than my current one, and I was able to find a really good solution from the community. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this snippet:

```
const foo 

const bar = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(foo).filter(value => value[1]))
```

In bar you have the filtered object.

To understand this, we can split it in three steps:

- With the Object.entries(foo) we got a list of foo entries. Each entry is a array with two values, the first one is a key and the second is the value.
- With the filter we got all entries in the entries array in the index 1 (the values) and filter if have a value. A empty string is considered a falsie value, so by using value[1] is enough.
- For last, with Object.fromEntries we got the filtered entries and we construct a object with this entries. If there is a empty string in foo, after the filter the key value combination isn't in the fromEntries param.

Comment: Awesome. This was it! Today you taught me about the existence of `Object.fromEntries()` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It will delete all empty property from your original object.

```js
const x = {
    "test1" : "",
    "test2" : "apple",
    "test3" : "oranges",
    "test5" : ""
};
Object.keys(x).filter(k => x[k] === '').map(k => delete x[k]);
console.log(x);
```

Comment: Thanks Dong, is there a way to have this line `Object.keys(x).filter(k => x[k] === '').map(k => delete x[k]);
` filter also return the final object?

Comment: It seems you've got the right answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.fromEntries` to rebuild a new filtered object:

```js
var obj = {
  "test1": "",
  "test2": "apple",
  "test3": "oranges",
  "test5": ""
};

obj = Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(obj).filter(k => obj[k] !== '').map(k => [k, obj[k]]));

console.log(obj);
```